# Java Encryption: NoSuchAlgorithmException error

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to encrypt some data using **AES Encryption and Decryption** . In there, I created a `Cipher` with following paramters,

Algorithm name - AES

Mode - CBC mode

Padding - PKCS7

```
Cipher aesCipherForEncryption = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING");
```

Following exception is throwing when I run my encryption code.

```
No Such Algorithm exists java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting DES/CBC/PKCS7Padding.
```

This is my source code,

```
    String strDataToEncrypt = new String();
    String strCipherText = new String();
    String strDecryptedText = new String();

    try {
        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGen.init(128);
        SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();

        final int AES_KEYLENGTH = 128;  
        byte[] iv = new byte[AES_KEYLENGTH / 8];    
        SecureRandom prng = new SecureRandom();
        prng.nextBytes(iv);

        Cipher aesCipherForEncryption = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING");

        aesCipherForEncryption.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

        strDataToEncrypt = "Hello World of Encryption using AES ";
        byte[] byteDataToEncrypt = strDataToEncrypt.getBytes();
        byte[] byteCipherText = aesCipherForEncryption.doFinal(byteDataToEncrypt);

        strCipherText = new BASE64Encoder().encode(byteCipherText);
        System.out.println("Cipher Text generated using AES is " + strCipherText);


        Cipher aesCipherForDecryption = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING"); 

        aesCipherForDecryption.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        byte[] byteDecryptedText = aesCipherForDecryption.doFinal(byteCipherText);
        strDecryptedText = new String(byteDecryptedText);

        System.out.println(" Decrypted Text message is " + strDecryptedText);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException noSuchAlgo) {
        System.out.println(" No Such Algorithm exists " + noSuchAlgo);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException noSuchPad) {
        System.out.println(" No Such Padding exists " + noSuchPad);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException invalidKey) {
        System.out.println(" Invalid Key " + invalidKey);
    } catch (BadPaddingException badPadding) {
        System.out.println(" Bad Padding " + badPadding);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException illegalBlockSize) {
        System.out.println(" Illegal Block Size " + illegalBlockSize);
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException invalidParam) {
        System.out.println(" Invalid Parameter " + invalidParam);
    }
```

But this is working with **PKCS5** with same parameters in `Cipher`

Have any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encrypt text to AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232705/encrypt-text-to-aes-cbc-pkcs7padding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html), the mentioned padding `PKCS7`is not supported.

You may refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232705/encrypt-text-to-aes-cbc-pkcs7padding) for more information