# Decrypt AES-256 Cipher

Tags: encryption, salesforce-commerce-cloud

I am using Cipher.decrypt to decrypt AES-256. In saltOrIV I am sending it as follows:

```
var ivBytes = Encoding.fromHex("000000000000000000000000");
var ivSend = Encoding.toBase64(ivBytes);

cipher.decrypt(bodyBase64, key, "AES/GCM/PKCS5Padding", ivSend, 0);
```

But I am getting the following exception: `com.demandware.beehive.core.internal.crypt.EncryptionException: com.demandware.beehive.core.internal.crypt.EncryptionException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Unsupported parameter: javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec`

Can someone help me with what i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: [AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivs);](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43858473/1820553)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `"AES/GCM/PKCS5Padding"` makes no sense, use `"AES/GCM/NoPadding"` instead **as GCM does not require any padding**.

To fix the problem, use `ivBytes` instead of `ivSend`. Hexadecimals and base 64 are textual representations of binary. The IV itself should consist of 12 binary bytes, not 16 bytes containing base 64 in ASCII.

Note that for GCM to be secure the "IV" should be a unique value, i.e. a so called nonce. Otherwise you'd have to use different keys for each encryption.

Comment: But in Salesforce documentation: "Note that ARCFOUR, Blowfish, DES, RC2, DESede, DESedeWrap, PBEWithMD5AndDES, PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES1, PBEWithSHA1AndDESede and PBEWithSHA1AndRC2_40 transformations have been deprecated. Also, PKCS5Padding is the only supported Padding. NOPADDING and ISO10126PADDING have been deprecated."

Comment: That makes no sense at all, just use `NoPadding` for GCM. If anything needs to be deprecated it is CBC mode. You can still use PBKDF2, lookup Java examples for that. Wow, I can see that class documentation, I'll try and contact SalesForce, because the person that wrote the method documentation needs to get a clue **pronto**.

Comment: Using "AES/GCM/NoPadding" I get the same exception. I also tried with PBKDF2. I think it's their method that they don't support. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you read the second section of my answer and did you replace `ivSend` with `ivBytes` in the call? I could not get that from your response!

Comment: Yes, I changed it. But it did not work. In C# or Java, I can decrypt. My problem is in the Salesforce Commerce Cloud.

Comment: Well, if the documentation is any indication I would not expect too much quality wise, unfortunately.