# Java AES Encryption and Decryption: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException

Tags: java, encryption, aes

newbie in Java AES! I am exploring and following the tutorial of [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-aes-encryption-decryption) and I got this error while seeing it for myself for 256 key length:
**Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Message must be a multiple of the block size without padding**

I have the below:
**main Method**
`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        System.out.println("Encrypt/Decrypt a string");
        //3 params for AES algo: (1) input data, (2) secret key, (3) and IV
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputKey;
        int inputSecretKey = 256;
        IvParameterSpec IV;
        
        
        //step 1: input
        System.out.print("Input: ");
        inputKey = scanner.nextLine();
        
        //step 2: generate secret key

        System.out.println("Generating secret key with size "+inputSecretKey);
        SecretKey secretKey1 = generateKey(inputSecretKey);
        
        //step 3: generate IV
        IV = generateIv();
        
        //step 4: print
        String cipherText = encrypt("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", inputKey, secretKey1, IV);
        String plainText = decrypt("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", inputKey, secretKey1, IV);
        Assertions.assertEquals(inputKey, plainText);
        System.out.println("Encrypted: "+cipherText+" [size : "+cipherText.length()+"]");
        System.out.println("Decrypted: "+plainText+" [size : "+plainText.length()+"]");
        
        
        scanner.close();
        
    }
```

`

**generateKey Method**
`

```
public static SecretKey generateKey(int n) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGen.init(n);
        SecretKey key = keyGen.generateKey();
        return key;
    }
```

`

**generateIv Method**
`

```
public static IvParameterSpec generateIv() {
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);
        return new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    }
```

`

**encrypt Method**
`

```
public static String encrypt(String algorithm, String input, SecretKey key,
            IvParameterSpec iv) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException,
            BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
            
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
            byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());
            return Base64.getEncoder()
                .encodeToString(cipherText);
    }
```

`

**decrypt Method** (I included which specific line is eclipse pointing me at)
`

```
public static String decrypt(String algorithm, String cipherText, SecretKey key,
            IvParameterSpec iv) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException,
            BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
            
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
            byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder()
                .decode(cipherText)); //<-------- GETTING ERROR IN THIS LINE
            return new String(plainText);
        }
```

`

I tried searching but I think no one has encountered this yet. The only thing I understood is AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding stands for algorithm/mode/padding. I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935068/what-are-the-cipher-padding-strings-in-java) though I am not sure what to use. I am quite confused on what I should change in the code and the root cause of the error.

I am trying inputs like "hello" or "dFet4Q2fi" if that helps.

Comment: can you add error stack trace, als can you try int inputSecretKey = 128 and check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of your `decrypt` method must be the cipherText not the input:

```
    String plainText = decrypt("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", cipherText
            , secretKey1, IV);
```

BTW: Take care of java naming conventions. Variable names should start with lower case character

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake! It works now. Also noted with the naming conventions. Would also like to know what triggers this specific error?

Comment: If you decode *Hallo* as Base64 encoded string, it is not a valid AES value