# CipherInputStream and CipherOutputStream are not generating files

Tags: java, encryption

I have the following code.  However the files `b.xlsx` and `c.xlsx` are of 0 bytes.  Why is `CipherOuputSteam` not working?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    KeyPair keys = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA").generateKeyPair();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keys.getPublic());

    FileInputStream fis;
    FileOutputStream fos;
    CipherOutputStream  cos;

    fis = new FileInputStream("C:/temp/a.xlsx");
    fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/temp/b.xlsx");

    cos = new CipherOutputStream (fos, cipher);

    byte[] block = new byte[8];
    int i;
    while ((i = fis.read(block)) != -1) {
        cos.write(block, 0, i);
    }
    cos.close();
    fos.close();



    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keys.getPrivate());
    CipherInputStream cis1, cis2;
    fis = new FileInputStream("c:/temp/b.xlsx");
    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
    fos = new FileOutputStream("c:/temp/c.xlsx");

    while ((i = cis.read(block)) != -1) {
        fos.write(block, 0, i);
    }
    fos.close();
    fis.close();
    cis.close();
}
```

Comment: I would start by trying a much larger buffer than 8 bytes, more like 4096. The 8-byte buffer probably makes it impossible for `CipherOutputStream` to do its job. If any exception is thrown you should edit it and the stack trace into your post.

Comment: That did not help.  I used 4096 and also 10,000.  It did not work.

Comment: Define 'did not work' please. Statements like that are 100% useless.

Comment: You can't use RSA that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in your usage - which is incorrect and in the implementation of `CipherOutputStream` which masks a very important exception - `IllegalBlockSizeException`.

The problem is that you cannot use an RSA key to encrypt data which is longer than the size of the key (which is 128 bytes in your example). 
you should use a symmetric encryption algorithm for large blocks of data - e.g. **AES**.

If you want to use asymmetric keys for a reason (safe transmition of data for example) - you can find a good example on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10007285/357360).