# CipherInputStream never throws exception

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I have a method like. It works fine but the problem is when I try to decrypt a file which is having wrong padding or even which is not encrypted at all. Usually I believe **cipher.doFinal(..)** usually throws some exception related to `IllegalBlockSizeException`,
`BadPaddingException`. I believe its due to masking of those exception as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15472762). My question is can I detect those exceptions cases?

```
public myDecryptMethod(byte[] sessionKey, FileInputStream encryptedFileStream) throws Exception{
....
    SecretKeySpec symmKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(sessionKey, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    Cipher symmCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec("0000000000000000".getBytes());
    symmCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, symmKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);

    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(encryptedFileStream, symmCipher);

    byte[] inputByteArray = new byte[10240];
    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    while (true) {
        int length = cis.read(inputByteArray);
        if (length < 0)
            break;
        outStream.write(inputByteArray, 0, length);
    }

    outStream.close();
    byte[] data = outStream.toByteArray();
    InputStream inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

    cis.close();

    return inStream;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There have been discussions about this in bouncycastle-dev and openjdk-security. Oracle [thinks](http://markmail.org/message/q3j53bbtyzrncauh?q=net.java.openjdk#query%3anet.java.openjdk%20page:1%20mid%3agmsivf4jsdc5d6k3%20state%3aresults) this is intended behavior and with JCE's ciphers which do not do the authentication check on close the consider it safe.

BC ciphers act differently as they allow to stream and (and release unauthenticated data).

Your option would be to use BCs stream `org.bouncycastle.crypto.io.CipherInputStream` instead. They fixed the stream (>1.50). [Phillipp wrote](http://blog.philippheckel.com/2014/03/01/cipherinputstream-for-aead-modes-is-broken-in-jdk7-gcm/) a good blog about all that.