# Large data not encrypted with RSA Encryption

Tags: java, android, encryption, rsa

**My Problem:**

My encryption code ***working fine for below 64 characters***. but if it exceeds 64 character I got following error

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: input must be under 64 bytes
```

**Encryption code**

```
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        rsaEncrypted= Base64.encodeToString(encryptedBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

**Key generation code**

```
      KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
      keyGen.initialize(512);
      KeyPair keypair = keyGen.genKeyPair();
      PublicKey pub = keypair.getPublic();
      byte[] pubs = pub.getEncoded();
```

**My question:**

It's possible encrypt large text with 512 bits of keys? Any mistake in my code?

Note: If anyone want full of code I will update later.

Comment: the size of the data to be encrypted is limited by the size of the RSA key. Use a larger key or use symmetric encryption

Comment: @pedrofb thanks for the info

Comment: Why bother with a bounty when the question was answered?

Comment: may this Que. helps you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007147/getting-a-illegalblocksizeexception-data-must-not-be-longer-than-256-bytes-when

Comment: @JamesKPolk In our iOS project team completed large text with 512 bit keys. That's the reason for bounty. I want to know any other possibilities with 512 bit keys.

Comment: [512 bit RSA keys are way too short for encryption.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-155)

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen thanks for confirmation

Comment: As an aside, you should avoid using ECB padding. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation explains well why with the images of the linux penguin.

Comment: Please consider this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/71268250/1711555

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a direct quote from the seminal book titled `Cryptography Engineering` by Ferguson, Schneier, and Kohno,

> Encrypting a message is the canonical application of RSA, yet it is **almost never used in practice**. The reason is simple: **the size of the message that can be encrypted using RSA is limited by the size of n**. In real systems, you cannot even use all the bits, because the encoding function has an overhead. This **limited message size** is too **impractical** for most applications, and because the RSA operation is **quite expensive** in computational terms, you don’t want to split a message into smaller blocks and encrypt each of them with a separate RSA operation.

In other words, for a n-bit RSA key, the maximum length of data RSA can encrypt in bytes is

```
Floor(n/8) - 11
```

where 11 bytes is for padding

So for a key size of 512 bits, the maximum length of data that can be encrypted is,

```
512/8 - 11 = 53 bytes
```

Again from the book `Cryptography Engineering`,

> The solution used almost everywhere is to choose a random secret key K, and encrypt K with the RSA keys. The actual message m is then encrypted with key K using a block cipher or stream cipher. So instead of sending something like E<sub>RSA</sub>(m), you send E<sub>RSA</sub>(K),E<sub>K</sub>(m).

Basically, it's telling you do the following to get over the limitation of RSA,

1. Generate a secret key, `K` using an algorithm such as AES.
2. Encrypt the plaintext, `m`, with the newly generated secret key to get cipher text, say E<sub>K</sub>(m).
3. Encrypt the secret key a RSA public key, E<sub>RSA</sub>(K).
4. Sent the client the cipher text, E<sub>K</sub>(m), and the encrypted key E<sub>RSA</sub>(K).
5. The client can decrypt E<sub>RSA</sub>(K) with the RSA private key to get `K`.
6. The client then decrypt the cipher text, E<sub>K</sub>(m) with `K` to get `m`.

Comment: Please consider this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/71268250/1711555. This doesn't require Hybrid Encryption

Answer (score 14):

The number of bytes you can encrypt in one **RSA** block is dictated by the key size used minus any bytes taken up for padding.

Generally **RSA** is not suited for bulk encryption as it's quite slow. Instead use a symmetric encryption algorithm like **AES** if you can. If you really need the two key's of RSA, use a Hybrid approach where you encrypt the data with a random symmetric key, and then encrypt that key with the RSA key.

A benefit of using symmetric encryption is also that the libraries automatically supports bulk encryption - which they don't for RSA.