# openssl_public_encrypt return empty output on large inputs

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

I'm trying to encrypt a CSR with another public cert.. It works fine if I take a small part of the CSR and put through the encryption.. But as I take a larger and larger piece of the csr it returns and empty encryption?

```
$csr = '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';

$public = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----'."\n"
.'MIIEpjCCAo6gAwIBAgICE54wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwdTEnMCUGA1UEAxMeQkQg'."\n"
.'QmFua0Nvbm5lY3QgUHJpbWFyeSBDQSBUZXN0MRwwGgYDVQQHExNFcnJpdHNvZSBG'."\n"
.'cmVkZXJpY2lhMQwwCgYDVQQLEwNWQkYxETAPBgNVBAoTCEJhbmtkYXRhMQswCQYD'."\n"
.'VQQGEwJESzAeFw0xNTA1MjkxNTEzMTBaFw0yMDA1MjkxNTEyMzVaMHMxJTAjBgNV'."\n"
.'BAMTHEJEIEJhbmtDb25uZWN0IEJhbmtkYXRhIFRlc3QxHDAaBgNVBAcTE0Vycml0'."\n"
.'c29lIEZyZWRlcmljaWExDDAKBgNVBAsTA1ZCRjERMA8GA1UEChMIQmFua2RhdGEx'."\n"
.'CzAJBgNVBAYTAkRLMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAwoRE'."\n"
.'MBiGuTNtXVYwGqPUtbdLfYs461nL3Kpe5JvZyOtOKVrnhyBF3Ap5D6hR9u5J1RT4'."\n"
.'CfvNfC2EzATUfORIRvt3SG1+JejtBNcub9BilpAB50puVCcsO6xZqQQQbGe/1xj8'."\n"
.'aSAA5WyedAQPFLaHBIM6rr/0p+BSzvjjYGGfg77LOm+cT2cDbg8El9RMd5RUbXjC'."\n"
.'+Nimx8nw/SKuqmETLr9Ctxa5rzSEHF3g1GSpW7LsiPPe87ebv7tdhRFQ5V55xcKk'."\n"
.'aqjZNYSuK4AGKLeOh8zmEZJB5KhR0EpjVlTo4NLrodRce6nNu3eocTGd+wu8raVD'."\n"
.'qHO9xfYdwztQF4dj2QIDAQABo0IwQDAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUAnHWLJb8lhqWn6LbHf13'."\n"
.'hwtcTHUwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUhDYWOyZP7phaO8f6tPt8Uw8MtokwDQYJKoZIhvcN'."\n"
.'AQELBQADggIBAFxf4QCazXaZTqT9E24JJSBTOiq4Wa8431UfCnKpMfrN8ES9+S2h'."\n"
.'JXLcqfPVyUj/flYuJqECJSVjE5InwDmzAOmaMkUcdUOH9vOJiRwIm8Iu83RN9mKc'."\n"
.'bX2XyeeU2en24dP9EVqCRYDEcT8v7dGS1sRLrt8r07VJABq6C1LeuBoMJSNF7CE+'."\n"
.'hTBlPxccL2zLZjsvuPkm7w590SJpo3uODo4wNHRF/fO+yb4QIuUEjI81sIWoyqla'."\n"
.'M9NoZ+jZ8jNsUqtMmWiPR9pscBidC5ylb6/xfIrvY9P4u1GADM7mxT1D0x56Y7md'."\n"
.'1YlEvY3EOMjk1zlkLlPrRhqdfvk6YnCX+WRaFDPXau11uYfxw2UjqV4UoSQxWoiW'."\n"
.'efzJIHYKPJjQkyPutNvstTsJ53D/TmA2gLFu475lk4Uy/eYCvmdbUncIXTuATZge'."\n"
.'Zq0IOfP15J/FFa6nq25gjTc/7AIXH3IaFwvMDzLln7sNl5DMGQTGeXPPUUwJgtU8'."\n"
.'L4Mk9QLqUG8GgO3WJixy5rv/pU0AqLzZrqsnGOJ+zmUPMums2bNSahYuN/zhGT2R'."\n"
.'MGLUfpIrmFxKP9x6TxfXRSPVFbTXF8TrQk9LkOPXKf0JxuNT9MjmEmnvWfWEhUBu'."\n"
.'hfu507iTkyjx1yRbHRjz2OhSBY3c++IpvOvhef3NbM+bOJirR6yD3VR6'."\n"
.'-----END CERTIFICATE-----'."\n";

// smaller piece of csr
$csr = 'MIIC6jCCAdICAQAw';

$public_cert = openssl_pkey_get_public($public);
openssl_public_encrypt($csr, $enc_data, $public_cert);
openssl_free_key($public_cert);
echo "enc_data: $enc_data\n";
```

Comment: RSA is not ment for bulk encryption, and implementations thus only support encrypting one block of data .. the size of one block is dependent of the key size .. [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51761721/large-data-not-encrypted-with-rsa-encryption/51767460#51767460).

Comment: Ok, thanks.. I don't know if you have experience with XML security? I need to encrypt some data in an XML document