# How to do RSA Encryption and Decryption on a large data in Java

Tags: java, android, rsa, bouncycastle, encryption-asymmetric

I am trying to perform Asymmetric Encryption and Decryption using RSA and OAEPPadding on actually larger data, say, 10 KB.

Many Stackoverflow articles mentioned to use the Hybrid approach [Assymmetric + Symmetric] but I am not looking for that. I purposely require Asymmetric Encryption.

I initialized the Encrypt and Decrypt Ciphers as follows:

```
mDecryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/OAEPPadding", new BouncyCastleProvider());
mDecryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, mPrivateKey);
Log.d(TAG, "Decrypt Cipher is successfully created");

mEncryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/OAEPPadding", new BouncyCastleProvider());
mEncryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, mPublicKey);
Log.d(TAG, "Encrypt Cipher is successfully created");
```

Following is the code by which I am trying to Encrypt or Decrypt the large data of size 10 KB.

```
// Encrypt
byte[] encryptedPayload = mEncryptCipher.doFinal(payload);

// Decrypt
byte[] decryptedPayload = mDecryptCipher.doFinal(payload);
```

Following is the exception I received:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: too much data for RSA block
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2205)
```

Please let me know how to perform RSA Encryption and Decryption on large data.

Comment: The answer is: **don't do this. Use hybrid encryption instead.** RSA is not designed to be used as block cipher. Additionally there are some attacks on RSA if used directly for encryption if the padding predictable (which could be the case as you want to maximize the data and minimize the padding).

Answer (score 1):

The Java Cipher objects allow us to retrieve the block sizes and using that we would be performing a repetitive kind of encryption as well as decryption which would let us over-come the **"too much data for RSA block"** exception.

Following is the logic for Encryption:

```
public byte[] encrypt(String data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Encryption begins");
    byte[] payload = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    int payloadLength = payload.length;
    int blockSize = mEncryptCipher.getBlockSize();
    Log.d(TAG, "blockSize: " + blockSize + "; payloadLength: " + payloadLength);

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int start = 0, end = 0;
    while (end < payloadLength) {
        end = end + blockSize;
        if (end > payloadLength) {
            end = payloadLength;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "start: " + start + "; end: " + end + "; block: " + (end - start));
        try {
            byte[] encryptedSlice = mEncryptCipher.doFinal(payload, start, (end - start));
            Log.d(TAG, "Encrypted Slice Length: " + encryptedSlice.length);
            stream.write(encryptedSlice);
            start = end;
        } catch (IOException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "update failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }
    byte[] encryptedPayload = stream.toByteArray();
    try {
        stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "encryptedPayload length: " + encryptedPayload.length);
    byte[] base64EncryptedPayload = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(encryptedPayload);
    Log.d(TAG, "base64EncryptedPayload length: " + base64EncryptedPayload.length);
    Log.d(TAG, "Encryption ends");
    return base64EncryptedPayload;
}
```

Following is the logic for Decryption:

```
public String decrypt(byte[] base64EncodedData) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Decryption begins");
    Log.d(TAG, "base64EncodedData length: " + base64EncodedData.length);
    byte[] encryptedData = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(base64EncodedData);
    Log.d(TAG, "encryptedData length: " + encryptedData.length);

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int payloadLength = encryptedData.length;
    int blockSize = mDecryptCipher.getBlockSize();
    int start = 0, end = 0;
    while (start < payloadLength) {
        end = end + blockSize;
        if (end > payloadLength) {
            end = payloadLength;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "start: " + start + "; end: " + end + "; block: " + (end - start));
        try {
            byte[] decryptedBlockData = mDecryptCipher.doFinal(encryptedData, start, (end - start));
            Log.d(TAG, "decryptedBlockData Length: " + decryptedBlockData.length);
            stream.write(decryptedBlockData);
            start = end;
        } catch (BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Slicing failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }
    String payload = stream.toString();
    try {
        stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Decryption ends");
    return payload;
}
```

Please note that in my case following are the details of the Cipher objects:

**EncryptCipher:**

```
getBlockSize: 470
getAlgorithm: RSA/None/OAEPPadding
getProvider Name: BC
getProvider Info: BouncyCastle Security Provider v1.70
```

**DecryptCipher:**

```
getBlockSize: 512
getAlgorithm: RSA/None/OAEPPadding
getProvider Name: BC
getProvider Info: BouncyCastle Security Provider v1.70
```

I am open to any better solution as well.

Comment: Technically, this is possible. But where do you see the advantage? (1) Asymmetric encryption is significantly slower than symmetric encryption. (2) Because of the maximum message size (e.g. max. 190 bytes for a 2048 bits key and OAEP with SHA256) even a small message like 10K has to be split many times and correspondingly many RSA encryptions have to be performed, in contrast to a *single* AES encryption. Again, inperformant and more expensive to implement.

Comment: And another, there is no integrity to protect the order of the messages...

Comment: @Topaco: I totally agree that Hybrid is best as it is fast and doesn't require slicing the larger payload into multiple blocks, but since I belong to the Client-Side and have no say on the Server-side I am bound to do this. I did share this concern to the Server-side team.

Comment: @kelalaka: Integrity is confirmed, there is no chance of such a problem but if you insist could you please elaborate on the issue?

Comment: One can play, delete, insert, and mix of the chunks. See how [I've advised for AES-GCM](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/86081/18298)

Comment: In contrast to wide spread textbook answers on this topic, I think slower performance compared to established symmetric encryption works for security in view of brute force attacks ;) Still I would consider authentication of the encrypted data, e.g. by adding a CMAC tag or an RSA signature, or extending the raw message protocol by such.